# Why are my images not loading when uploaded to Heroku

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

I can not get my images to show up when I upload my site to heroku. I've used relative paths with previous apps in the past but I do not know why they are not working in this case. I've tried adding ../ /../ and absolutely nothing has worked.

[my heroku app](https://elena-knapp.herokuapp.com/)

Comment: It gives this error - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found), it looks like your images not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the paths are correct, check the filename extensions of your images in heroku. Sometimes if your images are saved with the filename extension written in upper case, you can get this kind of problems.